# How to find commits by a specific user in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

Our project uses Git as the version control system and recently I needed to review someone's commits. How can I see a list of commits made by a specific user?

Comment: @RobertHarvey you marked this is as duplicate of 4259996 but actually 4259996 is duplicate of this

Comment: Possibly this is not a duplicate, if he meant to find the commit contents here (= the actual diffs).

Answer (score 241):

`git log --author=<pattern>` will show the commit log filtered for a particular author. (`--committer` can be used for committer if the distinction is necessary).

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: You mean author. `--committer` is for the committer. The two are different if, for example, the commit is from a patch sent by email. Then the committer (a maintainer) and the author are two different people.

Comment: True. Updated answer to mention both.

Comment: does this search all branches or only current branch?

Answer (score 104):

Try this:

```
git log --author=<name or email>
```

or pass the same option to `gitk`, or if already in gitk, go to view > new view, and fill in the appropriate field. The name doesn't have to be exact; it's matched as a regex (a substring, in the trivial case) against the author field.

Comment: Just note that if do this in `gitk`, it will also show the parent commit for context (the white circles). You can't change that behavior AFAIK.