# retrieving github comment on commit

Tags: github

Few months ago, I commented on github (from the web interface) a commit of another developer (it was just a normal commit, not a pull request). 
Now I cannot find that commit anymore. Is there a way to retrieve, for example, a complete list of all the comments that I have done with my github account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find commits by a specific user in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954477/how-to-find-commits-by-a-specific-user-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your public activity. For instance, if your github username is `foobar`, you could go to `https://github.com/foobar?tab=activity` once logged in and see a list of all activity, including comments.

Comment: This method would be ok, but unfortunately it seems that activity is limited to the last 10 days... :-(

Comment: You're right. Github returns last 30 items. On the API page (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/), they say they support paging, but as far as I've tested it, they don't (I get an empty response on page #2). Perhaps google search (https://www.google.com/?q=site:github.com+GITHUB_USERNAME_HERE) to the resuce?