# How do I query the git commit history?

Tags: git

So maybe I'm asking the question the wrong way, but I cannot find information on how to do this. I have a large git repository with many commits over the last two years by many people. Is there a way that anyone has ever figured out for how I query the git commit history? I am an SQL guy, so I'm used to using SQL to query a database (or even grep or find to query my filesystem).

These are example queries I'd like to run:

- All commits whose message contains the text "xyz"
- All commits whose message is LIKE '%xyz'
- All commits done by user person@company.com
- All commits that are the child of commit 1234abcd
- All commits between date 1 and date 2
- AND/OR combinations of the above

If I could even export the git log, then I could use a different tool to get most of this information (though ancestral querying/querying by branch might be difficult). Sometimes it would be nice to just go to the command line and query really quickly to try to find a commit from a while back.

Comment: Mostly using `git log` arguments like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746684/how-to-search-through-all-git-and-mercurial-commits-in-the-repository-for-a-cert) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954477/how-to-find-commits-by-a-specific-user-in-git). If you read the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for `git log` you'll see there are lots of such options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git log` with various switches as explained by the [git-log docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log) e.g.:

All commits whose message contains the text "xyz" will be:

```
git log --grep=xyz
```

> --grep=<pattern> Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the specified pattern (regular expression). With more
>   than one --grep=<pattern>, commits whose message matches any of the
>   given patterns are chosen (but see --all-match).

All commits done by user person@company.com will be:

```
git log --author=person@company.com
```

> --author=<pattern>
>   --committer=<pattern> Limit the commits output to ones with author/committer header lines that match the specified pattern
>   (regular expression). With more than one --author=<pattern>, commits
>   whose author matches any of the given patterns are chosen (similarly
>   for multiple --committer=<pattern>).

and so on based on the [git-log docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log).