# Check if all pull requests have been cherry-picked in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit, pull-request

I have pull requests that were merged into some branch by specific Authors within a date range.

How would I check if all those pull requests have been cherry picked into another branch?

We are only concerned about merged pull requests by specific authors and dates, and we need to make sure that we have cherry-pick all of them..

What's the recommendation in this case?

The core of this question is as its title, Lets say we have `staging` branch that has 27 pull requests made by `userA` within a range of date and other pull requests that we are not concerned about, then how can I make sure that all those 27 requests have been cherry-picked into branch `mobile` and that there isn't any missed pull request from them?

Its different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313309/list-git-commits-to-master-branch-between-two-dates) question as I am not listing commits at some branch, but I am checking if *all* pull requests within specific criteria have been cherry-picked from some branch into other branch of interest.

Comment: `git log`: [Between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313309/list-git-commits-to-master-branch-between-two-dates) and [specific author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954477/how-to-find-commits-by-a-specific-user-in-git)

Comment: kindly check my `EDIT` above as I explain that my question is different.